# Как сравнить две таблицы DataTable одного типа

Tags: .net, c#

Подскажите, как сравнить две таблицы DataTable одного типа?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static bool AreTablesEqual(DataTable t1, DataTable t2)
{
    if (t1.Rows.Count != t2.Rows.Count)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < t1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach(DataColumn col in t1.Columns)
        {
            if (!Equals(t1[i][col.Name], t2[i][col.Name]))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Cравнение DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626781/in-c-sharp-i-would-like-to-compare-datatables)

Comment: Я бы еще входные аргументы на null проверил, как в любом порядочном методе `Compare`.

Comment: как правильно заметили на SO таблицы должны быть предварительно одинаково сортированы.